# Last Import stuck in iPhoto Events folder after migrating to Photos app

Tags: macos, photos.app

I've just updated to the new Photos app on OS X and migrated my iPhoto library to the new app. While getting used to all the changes, I've noticed a problem: it seems that the Last Import album is stuck in the iPhoto Events folder for some reason. (Does the iPhoto database consider Last Import to be an "event"?)

I can tell that the lone album is Last Import because:

- I've moved all other albums out of the folder, but it still says that there is one album left inside, even though the view shows that it is empty inside.
- When I go back to the top-level album view, the iPhoto Events folder is shown to contain one album thumbnail unlike the inside view. The thumbnail within the folder matches the thumbnail of Last Import.
- When I move photos out of Last Import and import a different set of photos, both thumbnails update.

Now here's the bigger problem: if I delete the iPhoto Events folder now, I will lose the Last Import album permanently with no apparent way to get it back through the UI or the application's preferences. (I imagine I can get it back by editing either the app's plist in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Photos/Data/Library/Preferences` or one or more files in the package, but I'm not sure where to look.)

I've tried

- importing new photos to see if Last Import will reappear, but it doesn't.
- repairing the Photos library using the same method as iPhoto (hold <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> when opening the app), but it doesn't help.
- repairing the iPhoto library *before* migrating to Photos, but it doesn't help either.
- undoing the deletion, but it just brings back both Last Import and the iPhoto Events folder.

I have re-imported the original iPhoto library for now so that its original state is preserved. What can I do to separate Last Import from the iPhoto Events folder so I can safely remove the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fresh new iPhoto library, populated it with some photos, and migrated that library to Photos, but I could not reproduce this problem. So it looks like another [problem with my original iPhoto library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78928/rebuilding-iphoto-library-causes-issues-with-itunes-photo-sync). Great.

So I decided to look directly in the Photos library database to see what was going on. The Photos library database can be found in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/Library.apdb`; this is an SQLite database that can be opened using the command-line `sqlite3` tool, or any GUI you prefer.

If you're about to follow the steps in my answer past this point, **remember to back up the library file before proceeding**.

The schema for `RKAlbum` contains a `folderUuid` column that associates an album with a folder (in `RKFolder`). In the Photos library that was migrated from the fresh iPhoto library, the Last Import album looks like this:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT name, folderUuid FROM RKAlbum WHERE name = 'Last Import';
Last Import|LibraryFolder
```

But in the Photos library that was created from my original iPhoto library, the album looks like this:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT name, folderUuid FROM RKAlbum WHERE name = 'Last Import';
Last Import|cQeJj7YPRmSxHysWN+ql4w
```

Notice that `folderUuid` here is a generated string and not `'LibraryFolder'`. Obviously, this is an arbitrary folder — specifically the iPhoto Events folder that is created as part of the migration process. And sure enough:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT uuid, name FROM RKFolder WHERE uuid = 'cQeJj7YPRmSxHysWN+ql4w';
cQeJj7YPRmSxHysWN+ql4w|iPhoto Events
```

As an immediate workaround, changing the column directly seems to work:

```sql
sqlite> UPDATE RKAlbum SET folderUuid = 'LibraryFolder' WHERE name = 'Last Import';
```

Now opening Photos and deleting the iPhoto Events folder leaves Last Import intact. Importing new photos doesn't cause any further problems; the Last Import folder behaves as it always did, and should.

---

Out of curiosity I decided to find out what was causing Photos to place Last Import in the iPhoto Events folder in the first place.

Turns out, in my original iPhoto library, the `folderUuid` of Last Import was not `'LibraryFolder'`, but `'AllProjectsItem'` — the same as the original Events category:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT name, folderUuid FROM RKAlbum WHERE name = 'Last Import';
Last Import|AllProjectsItem
sqlite> SELECT name, folderUuid FROM RKAlbum WHERE folderUuid = 'AllProjectsItem';
Events|AllProjectsItem
Last Import|AllProjectsItem
```

This is not the case in the fresh iPhoto library:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT name, folderUuid FROM RKAlbum WHERE name = 'Last Import';
Last Import|LibraryFolder
```

Fixing the incorrect column in the original iPhoto library database (with the same `UPDATE` statement as above) seems to fix the Last Import folder when migrating to Photos as well. I think I'll go with this instead since it corrects both the old and new libraries.

Like in my [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78928/rebuilding-iphoto-library-causes-issues-with-itunes-photo-sync), I don't understand why or how my original iPhoto library reached that state in the first place, or why repairing/rebuilding the library didn't help at all. Was I bitten by a rare bug in iPhoto? Was I using iPhoto incorrectly? Either way, I'm lucky that I know a thing or two about SQLite and was therefore able to fix this on my own — if in the unlikely event someone has run into this very same issue, I hope this post will be helpful to them.

Once again, **be sure to back up the entire library first**.